# Outlook with GMail (less secure app)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

My employer uses gmail/gsuite for emails, coming from a microsoft camp and adapted to outlook therefore I am trying to configure to use outlook to access the email/calendars etc. Now I turned on the 2 step verification on gmail, generate an app password, try to create an account to connect to gmail, outlook keep saying 'unable to connect', while on the same time google says 'prevented a sign in from less secure app', and since it is a corp managed account I cannot change google to allow get access from 'less secure app'

Question, so this means no way to connect to gmail from outlook? This is just sad!!

btw, I am using outlook 2016 for mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've answered your own question.

Google considers the authentication methods available in Outlook to be "less secure" and your company has decided they will prevent you from changing this setting.

Therefore, you are correct, you cannot connect your work Gmail account to your local Outlook client.

Comment: thanks, that is just sad... I can kiss outlook goodbye from now..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have outlook 2016 (and 2010, and 2003, and Mac ...) connected to Gmail.

If your company permits you to connect your Outlook account to your Gmail account, Google will let you do it.

Note, in this context, "Less secure" means "does not use Google Authentication".

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this for couple weeks. I had exact the same situation. My employer uses gmail as his corporate email provider, he force employees to use 2-way authentication and doesn't allow to use "[less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)". 
I was trying to use [application password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords), enabling access using [captcha](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha). Nothing has been working.

And finally I found [G Suite](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync). It is a tool which just synchronize gmail account with outlook.

[Gmail in outlook without 'less secure apps'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Re8.png)

It doesn't configure outlook with standard mail configuration but it adds account named G Suite.

[G suite mail configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0itd7.png)

I am using it for couple days now and it is working perfectly. It syncs mail and calendar without any problems.